# Grep Negation Question

Tags: grep, curl

```
(curl -s 'https://wayfair.com' | grep -q "Sale") && osascript SendMessage.scpt 5555551234 https://wayfair.com
```

The above works in conjuction with the script below to send a text message if Wayfair have the word sale on their main page.  Wayfair is just an example.

```
on run {targetBuddyPhone, targetMessage}
tell application “Messages”
set targetService to 1st account whose service type = iMessage
set targetBuddy to participant targetBuddyPhone of targetService
send targetMessage to targetBuddy
end tell
end run
```

Is there a way to run the same command, but negate the information?  For example, read through Wayfair's homepage and if Wayfair.com **DOES NOT** have the word "Sale" on their site, it would then send me a text?

I'm writing this in applescript and I am super new.....

Comment: Change the `&&` to `||`.

Comment: I'll give it a go.  What does the | | do?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, you're a genius, thank you!!!

Comment: Any idea how I can put this into a bash file so I can put add the bash file to a crontab so it runs every minute?

Comment: Since the answer to your question is use the `||` which is explained in the answer to that other question, I will close this as a duplicate. Please ask about the cron issue separately, but try reading some cron tutorial first so you can ask about any tricky part. It might make more sense to ask on [apple.se] if it's about the macOS-specific applecscript as we're unlikely to know.